# How to call this.props from a static navigationOptions - react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to call a handlelogout() in onPress of button in the header of a stack navigator and then in the handlelogout() I am calling `this.props.logout` action which will call a navigation reducer to reset to login screen.....but `this.props.logout` doesnt call an action....nothing happens

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    console.log("navigation", navigation);

    return {
      title: "Profile List",
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: <Button title={"Logout"} onPress={() => params.handlelogout && params.handlelogout({ state: navigation.state })} />
    }
  };
```

this is my handlelogout function

```
handlelogout(state) {
    console.log("in handlelogout", this.props.logout, state);
    this.props.logout;
  }
```

[i am attaching the log i printed in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj0TQ.png)

here I am binding the logout to mapdispatchprops

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ReduxActions, dispatch);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the actual issue or just a mistake in the question code snippet, but you are not _calling_ the `this.props.logout` method. For that, you need to invoke the function with `this.props.logout()`.

Comment: jevakallio this.props.logout (reduxactions)is a dispatch action to an actioncreator and which calls a navigation reducer.....

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the button inside another element then handle your logout from that element/class.

```
import ButtonForLogout from './test/buttonforlogout';

...

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    console.log("navigation", navigation);

    return {
      title: "Profile List",
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: <ButtonForLogout />
    }
  };
```

buttonforlogout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ReduxActions } from './youractions';

class ButtonForLogout extends Component {

   render(){
   return(
      <View>
       <Button title={"Logout"} onPress={this.props.logout} />
      </View>
   );
   }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, ReduxActions)(ButtonForLogout);
```

Something like that.